# Image uploading by servlet gives Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, servlets

**Exception**

```
    Aug 06, 2015 5:09:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet FileUploadHandler as unavailable
Aug 06, 2015 5:09:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet FileUploadHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FileUploadHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileUploadHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FileUploadHandler</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileUploadHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**FileUploadHandler.java**

```
 package mypackage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/uploads";

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //process only if its multipart content
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                                         new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                    if(!item.isFormField()){
                        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    }
                }

               //File uploaded successfully
               request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            }          

        }else{
            request.setAttribute("message",
                                 "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
        }

        //request.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

**input.jsp**

```
 <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input name="upl" multiple="" type="file">
                           <input type="submit" value="upload">

                        </form>
```

While uploading a file to a directory i got exception of servlet. 
I want to upload image to directory using servlet or any other method suitable to upload and retrieve that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `servlet-class` must be the *fully qualified name* of the servlet class:

```
mypackage.FileUploadHandler
```

Comment: I have a question,..
i have mentioned that name of directory as "uploads" which is in the root of Web-Content. So, should i mention it as 
String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/uploads"; or i have to give full path to uploads folder?

Comment: You would be better off giving a full path

Answer (score 0):

Your `web.xml` is not configured correctly; the `<servlet-class>` must contain the full class name, including package, like so:

```
<servlet-class>mypackage.FileUploadHandler</servlet-class>
```